# Iphone launch image disappear very fast

Tags: iphone, ios, image, launch

The launch image appear and disappear very fast in the iPhone.
How can I control this time? How much seconds is the default?

Thanks

Comment: Having the launch image disappear very quickly and be replaced by a functional app is a good thing. Do NOT force your users to stare at a "splash screen". It's bad user experience and against Apple's guidelines.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `sleep(time in seconds)` function in the  `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to explicitly increase some time by yourself.

Eg :

```
sleep(3);
```

Will extend the time to 3 more seconds.

**Note** : As rmaddy said, make user stare at splash screen for a long time is not a good practice. But you can use this in customer's demand.

Happy coding. :)

Comment: gah! that's awful! just make your first view controller identical to your launch image, then dismiss it from an NSTimer or something like that. or with a tap. ugh! what if a call comes in, will sleep get interrupted?

Comment: iOS will kill your app if it takes 'too long' to launch; this will look identical to a crash to the user. So if you follow this route then be very careful indeed.

Comment: What Tommy said is true, but app that take more than around 20 seconds or so will be killed..You have to aware of that,so please don't make the interval more. But average usage will never cause any problem. Even 3 sec of delay using sleep function is applied in my app that is recently published in the App Store. :)

Answer (score 2):

There's no default — it stays up until your program has been loaded and returned from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

If you want to keep the image up under programmatic control then you'll need to place it on screen manually as the first thing the program displays, then dismiss it through the usual channels. This would be relatively easy on a pre-5 iPhone (just put up a big `UIImageView` with `Default.png` in it) but as of the iPhone 5 and with the iPad you're going to have to make some sort of decisions about which default screen to show.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to add a sleep time in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method as below:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.0f]; //add 3 seconds longer.
   //other code....
}
```